# Google reCaptcha - Number of Hits per Day

Tags: recaptcha

I am using Google reCaptcha in a Angular+Spring MVC application for user signIn. I would like to know if Google has any restriction on the number of hits it supports per day ( or week/month/year).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, I advise you to read [FAQ](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq)

To answer your question; (according to v1.0)

> **Does reCAPTCHA have the capacity to accommodate large amounts of traffic?**
>
> Definitely. reCAPTCHA has distributed locations and multiple servers.
>   The only thing we ask is to be contacted beforehand if you expect your
>   site to constantly need more than 1 million reCAPTCHAs solved per day.
>   reCAPTCHA is used by many large sites — we display over 100 million
>   CAPTCHAs every day.

I have also **tested** it (on v2) personally like a year ago, never had a problem with hundreds of thousands of requests and thousands of concurrent requests. So I think v1 answer is still valid or a lot flexible.